# XOM getting attribute from Node?

Tags: java, xml, xom

Shouldn't something like this work?

Assuming a document formatted as such:

```
<root>
   <element id = "a"></element>
</root>

Node node = doc.query("/root/element").get(0);
String id = node.getDocument().getRootElement().getAttribute("id");
```

When I print the value of the root element, it looks as if this should work. What's failing, here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your node to an Element, and you're good to go.

Comment: I dont get it. Isnt this what I already posted ? ["Can you try type casting Node to Element and also tell us what is failing."]

Comment: Comments are not answers. If you wanted acceptance, you should have posted the answer, rather than comment.

Answer (score 0):

node.getDocument().getRootElement() at this point you have the  element which does not have an attribute "id".

Try node.getAttribute("id") instead ? (assuming node is not null)

Comment: Can you try type casting Node to Element and also tell us what is failing. 

Also, any code pasted shown should not be considered compilable (and I hate downvoting because something does not compile). The idea is what should be looked at ?

Comment: When I print the root element retrieved, it shows <element id = "blah">...</element>, so I'm confused as to why that doesn't work.